# What does "Except" mean in this ATC request?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-pilot, frequency

I guess ATC wants the pilot to leave FL 280 for heavy traffic approaching from behind. But since I'm not sure, I wanted to ask. Also in the second quote from pilot, except should be expect, right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty common mistake people make in English, I won't mention any bias I have over which group ;)

Comment: Ahahaha, I can guess this specific group :D

Comment: It would be interesting to find the source of the information; also *text* would be preferable to images.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a **typo**. That is supposed to say **EXPECT** FLIGHT LEVEL 280 IN 10 MINUTES.

This means Atlasjet 123 is not yet cleared to the new altitude of FL280, but they can expect this clearance in 10 minutes. The reason the controller is not clearing them yet is a faster 747 behind, which would result in a conflict at the moment. Once that 747 has passed (in about 10 minutes), they will get cleared to FL280.

---

The second quote should also say **EXPECT**. They want to know for which runway they should prepare the approach.